# Migrate debian login from ldap to local login

Tags: linux, debian, ldap, openldap

we have a debian stretch machine on which the users login by ldap. Since we want to shut down our ldap server(not used anymore except by this single machine), i have to search for a way to migrate the users from openldap to the local login without disturbing the processes of the users, because some of them are running some long term science projects. Is there a way to do this?